# Android drawable не подгружает нужный background на Tablet (7, 10)

Tags: android

Здравствуйте, я начинающий программист и столкнулся с одной проблемой. Искал ответ в интернете но так и не нашел. Помогите пожалуйста.
  Есть у меня приложение на android и решил я сделать чтоб на разных расширениях подгружало разные background с помощью (drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi ...) Но тут что-то  пошло не так, На телефонах работает идеально. Но на Tablet (7, 10) подгружает только background из drawable-mdpi, а нужно чтоб подгружало из (drawable-xhdpi и drawable-xхhdpi). для Tablet (7, 10) сделал отдельные xml-файлы и поместил их в папки (layout-sw600dp, layout-sw720dp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все работает как и должно. DPI вашего таблета - mdpi, соответственно и загружать изображения он будет из drawable-mdpi. Если хотите, что бы на таблеты загружались более четкие изображения, то создайте папки drawable-sw600dp, drawable-sw720dp, и поместите туда нужные изображения (которые у вас сейчас в drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi)

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло!